# Sumproduct of specific list elements in a list

Tags: python, list, sumproduct

I have a string, which includes upper-case characters and substrings, which are in the form of an integer in a bracket (e.g.: (1)).

**Example string:**

```
in_str = '(3)(3)ABC(2)XY(5)PQRSTX(9)(2)TWO(7)SEVEN'
```

I have extracted the sub-strings to a nested list, where each sub-list contains the integer and the length of upper-case characters between it and the next sub-string.

**Example list:**

```
in_lst = [[3, 0], [3, 3], [2, 2], [5, 6], [9, 0], [2, 3], [7, 5]]
```

I would like to multiply the sub-lists by their first elements, which are directly connected (no upper-case string between them in the string) and replace used sub-lists with an empty one (will need that for the task), except one for each section, which contains the final sumproduct for given section.

**Example desired output:**

```
out_lst = [[], [9, 3], [2, 2], [5, 6], [], [18, 3], [7, 5]]
```

**Example output list in string:**

```
out_str = '(9)ABC(2)XY(5)PQRSTX(18)TWO(7)SEVEN'
```

Unfortunately, I am kinda lost on this one in terms of the proper approach, so I haven't been able to produce a code, which returns at least an approximate output list, so any help or tip regarding that is more than welcome!

Comment: `I have extracted the sub-strings to a nested list`, post your code for this part, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` to find the digits and the letter following them, then iterate over them and convert to the needed form

```
import re
split_lst = re.findall(r'\((\d)\)([A-Z]*)', in_str)
print (split_lst)
#[('3', ''), ('3', 'ABC'), ('2', 'XY'), ('5', 'PQRSTX'), ('9', ''), ('2', 'TWO'), ('7', 'SEVEN')]

out_str = ''.join(e for (n,s) in split_lst for e in (('(%s)' % (int(n)*len(s))), s) if s)
print (out_str)
#'(9)ABC(4)XY(30)PQRSTX(6)TWO(35)SEVEN'
```